# Prove that $\lim_{m \to \infty} (\lceil m U \rceil -mU ) \sim U(0,1)$

Tags: probability, limits

Title says it all. If you take a really large uniform random number and the distance from it to the next integer, you should get a uniform random number between $0$ and $1$ ($U$ everywhere in the equations is a uniform random number between $0$ and $1$).

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} (\lceil m U \rceil -mU ) \sim U(0,1)$$

---

For context, this identity is useful in proving the conjecture here: [Need help validating a proof that for any point process with MTBF $t$, the events in an interval sized $u$ will be $\frac{u}{t}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132321/need-help-validating-a-proof-that-for-any-point-process-with-mtbf-t-the-event), which says that if I take a large uniform random number and start an observation period there for any point process, the average number of events inside an interval size $u$ will be $\frac{u}{t}$ where $t$ is the mean time between events for the point process. Basically, you can rescale your time so that $t$ becomes $1$ unit and the result here shows that the time from the start of the interval to the next event will be uniform between $0$ and $t$.

Comment: Okay, nice result. What is $U$ in the limit?

Comment: $U$ everywhere is just a uniform random number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Why only in the limit?

Comment: Does it hold for all real $m$? I see it holds when $m$ is an integer, not obvious for a general real number.

Comment: @RohitPandey No, I was assuming $m$ integer in the question .

Comment: Regarding the meta post : Good enough questions stay. You improved yours, and that's all that matters. Thank you for the prompt response and wish you a good day ahead with good questions ,better answers and great conversations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$U(0,1)$ is standard notation for a uniform random variable so I will keep the name of the random variable (number) $V$ instead of $U$. Suppose $m\not\in\Bbb Z$.

Then $Y_m=mV\sim U(0,m)$ and $Z_m=\lceil Y_m\rceil-Y_m\in[0,1)$. The distribution function of $Z_m$,$$\begin{align*}F_{Z_m}(x)&=P(\lceil Y_m\rceil-Y_m\le x)\\&=\begin{cases}0,&x\le0\\P(Y_m\in[k-x,k],k\in\Bbb N_{\le\lfloor m\rfloor}),&0<x\le \lceil m\rceil -m\\P(Y_m\in[k-x,k],k\in\Bbb N_{\le\lfloor m\rfloor})+P(\lceil m\rceil-x\le Y_m\le m),&\lceil m\rceil -m<x<1\\1,&x\ge1 \end{cases}\end{align*}$$

Note that$$\begin{align*}&P(Y_m\in[k-x,k],k\in\Bbb N_{\le\lfloor m\rfloor})+P(\lceil m\rceil-x\le Y_m\le m)\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m\rfloor}\int_{k-x}^k\frac{dy}m+\frac1m\int_{\lceil m\rceil -x}^mdy\\&=\frac{x\lfloor m\rfloor}m+\underbrace{\frac1m\int_{\lceil m\rceil -x}^mdy}_{\le\frac1m}\end{align*}$$

so the underlined expression vanishes as $m\to\infty$ and the asymptotic behaviour of the second and third cases is identical. Taking the limit as $m\to\infty$,

$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{m\to\infty}F_{Z_m}(x)&=\begin{cases}0,&x\le0\\\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{x(m-\{m\})}m,&0<x<1\\1,&x\ge1 \end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}0,&x\le0\\x,&0<x<1\\1,&x\ge1 \end{cases}\\
&\sim U(0,1)
\end{align*}$$where $\{\cdot\}$ is the fractional part function.

Comment: When $m\in\Bbb Z$ our work is considerably reduced as the second case of $F_{Z_m}(x)$ applies when $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a visualization of cases 2 and 3 from the first conditional equation of @ShubhamJohri's answer (for my own future reference; this helps see why the equation is true). Pasting the equation here:

$$\begin{align*}F_{Z_m}(x)&=P(\lceil Y_m\rceil-Y_m\le x)\\&=\begin{cases}0,&x\le0\\P(Y_m\in[k-x,k],k\in\Bbb N_{\le\lfloor m\rfloor}),&0<x\le \lceil m\rceil -m\\P(Y_m\in[k-x,k],k\in\Bbb N_{\le\lfloor m\rfloor})+P(\lceil m\rceil-x\le Y_m\le m),&\lceil m\rceil -m<x<1\\1,&x\ge1 \end{cases}\end{align*}$$

[image]

In case-2, we have to ignore the purple area. But in case-3, some of the purple area turns green and adds an additional term. The orange regions are common to both cases.

Comment: That's an image that's incredibly hard to see.

Comment: It expands on the answer. I'd gladly post it as a comment but can I add images to comments?

Comment: @amWhy - changed the background of the image to white. Hopefully this makes it easier to see.

Comment: Thanks, @RohitPandey !

Answer (score 2):

Adding a proof that this works for $m \in \Bbb Z$ even if it isn't large. For some integer $0 \leq i \leq m$, if $V \in \left(\frac{i}{m},\frac{i+1}{m}\right)$ we have:

$$Y_m = (i+1) -m\left(\frac{U+i}{m}\right) = 1-U \sim U$$

Since this holds for all $i$, we get that $Y_m \sim U$.

Comment: This should have been part of you question.

Comment: I can edit and add it there now, let me know.. I came up with it much after I'd asked the question and an answer had been posted+accepted. What do I do in such cases (where I come up with some insight after people have posted answers)? If I edit the question, it might change the nature of it and make the answers look strange since they assumed the original question. Though admittedly, this wasn't the case here.

Comment: What is $I$? Do you mean $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: Oh, its the set of integers.. should I use another notation?

Comment: @RohitPandey Fixed.

Comment: Thanks.. yes, I thought there was another notation for integers I wasn't remembering :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another proof that relaying in a rather humble result from Fourier analysis: [Fejer's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671).

Notice that $\lceil x\rceil -x=1-\{x\}$, where $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$. Suppose $f\in \mathcal{C}[0,1]$, then the function $\phi(x)=f(1-\{x\})$ is a bounded $1$-periodic (i.e. periodic with period $1$).

Féjer's result states that for any $g\in L_1([0,1])$
$$ \int^1_0 g(x)\phi(nx))\,dx\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\int^1_0\phi(x)\,dx\Big)\Big(\int^1_0 g(x)\,dx\Big) $$
In particular, for $g\equiv1$ we get that
$$E[f(1-\{nU\})] = \int^1_0 f(1-\{nu\})\,du\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^1_0 f(1-u)\,du=E[f(U)]$$
since $1-U\stackrel{law}{=}U$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$?

Comment: The space of continuous functions in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: @RohitPandey: What I am doing (as others did through by directly using the CDF of $Y_m:=\lceil mU\rceil - mU$)  is to prove that $Y_m$ converges weakly to $U$ based on the definition of weak convergence: that is,  that for any bounded continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ (this is where $Y_m$ and $U$ take values) one has that $E[f(Y_m)]\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty} E[f(U)]$.

Comment: I see, that seems to be a stronger result! I'm not familiar with these techniques, so need some time to digest this. Very interesting and thanks for sharing!

Comment: You mean the method I used or the fact that  $E[f(Y_m)]\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty} E[f(U)]$ for any $f\in\mathcal{C}[0,1]$. The latter fact is what it means for a sequence of random variables ($Y_m$ in this case) to converge weakly to another random variable ($U$ in your case). It just so happen that for real valued random variables, weak convergence is equivalent to checking that $F_{Y_m}(y)=P[Y_m\leq y]\xrightarrow{m\rightarrow\infty}[U\leq y]=F_U(y)$ at Avery point $y$ where the cumulative distribution $F_U$ of $U$ is continuous (in the present case, any $y$). (***continue***)

Comment: All that is covered in may graduate books in Probability (Durret, Chapet 2, for example). The technique to prove the problem in your OP is a rather humble result from Fourier analysis that tells you how to average out integrals with respect a periodic function where the the frequency  is being increase. The other responders use the criteria I mentioned in my earlier comment (convergence of cumulative distributions at continuity points).

Comment: Finally, what I called Féjer formula does not appear as such in the literature. I learned of this result from a book of problems by Claude George, *Exerceises in Integration*, Springer-Verlag1, 1984, pp. 115-116, and who attributes it to Féjer.