# Lebesgue integration of fractional part in on $L^1[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, fractional-part

I was trying to solve the following problem:

Suppose $h\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $\int_0^1 h(x)dx=0$. For $x\ge 0$, let $\{ x \}$ represent the fractional part of $x$: $\{ x \}=x-p$, where $p$ is a positive integer such that $p\le x<p+1$. Show that

a) For any $0\le a \le b\le 1$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^b h(\{ nx \})dx=0$.

b) For any $g\in L^1[0,1]$, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 h(\{ nx \})g(x)dx=0$.

My initial idea was to use the Monotone Convergence Theorem by defining $h_n:=h(\{ nx \})$ on $[a,b] \subseteq [0,1]$, but I am struggling to justify why this would converge to zero (not really sure how to work with the fractional part here). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an application of a result by [Fejer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3741777/121671) which has been discussed before in MSE several times. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4139501/121671) is another such example