# For what distributions, $X$ is $E(\lfloor c-X \rfloor) = c-1$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Per the question here: [Prove that $E([c-U]) = c-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123742/prove-that-ec-u-c-1), it was proven that:

$$E(\lfloor c-U\rfloor) = c-1$$

if $U$ is a uniform random number between $0$ and $1$. I have some reason to suspect that this only holds for this particular distribution of $U$. I tried looking for counter-examples to this conjecture (considering the Beta distribution and some bimodal distributions) and couldn't find any. Is there a way to either prove this conjecture or disprove it via a counter-example?

The random variable, $U$ shouldn't depend on $c$ and the result should hold for all $c \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $U$ is a r.v.in $(0,1)$ that satisfies the condition of your problem, that is
$$E[\lfloor c-U\rfloor]=c-1$$
for all $c$ then it must be uniform.

Proof:  You have that if $n<c<n+1$,
$$c-1=\mathbb{E}[\textrm{floor}(c-U)]=nP(0<U\leq c-n)+(n-1)P(c-n<U \leq 1])$$
In particular, for any $0<c<1$ ($n=0$)
$$c-1=\mathbb{E}[\textrm{floor}(c-U)]=-P(c<U \leq 1)$$
From this, it follows that
$$c=1-P(c<U\leq 1)=P(0< U\leq c) $$

That shows that $U$ is uniform.

Comment: You answered the question I didn't quite ask, but wanted to ask; which is very impressive.

Answer (score 2):

You may modify the uniform distribution. Consider e.g. $U$ with density $f(t)=1/2( \chi_{[-1,0]}(t)+\chi_{[1,2]}(t))$. For $c\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $x\in[0,1)$ with $c=\lfloor c\rfloor+1$. Tjen we have

\begin{align*}
2E(\lfloor c-U\rfloor)&=\int_{-1}^0 (\lfloor c\rfloor +x-t)dt+\int_0^1(\lfloor c\rfloor +x-t) dt\\
&=\int_{-1}^{x-1}\lfloor c\rfloor +1 dt + \int_{x-1}^0 \lfloor c \rfloor dt + \int_{1}^{1+x}\lfloor c\rfloor -1 dt + \int_{1+x}^2 \lfloor c\rfloor -2 dt\\
&=x(\lfloor c \rfloor +1) + (1-x)\lfloor c\rfloor + x(\lfloor c\rfloor -1)+ (1-x)(\lfloor c\rfloor -2)\\
&=2(\lfloor c\rfloor + x -1)= 2(c-1)
\end{align*}

Comment: My solution does not contradict yours. What I proved is that is $U$ is supported in $(0,1)$ then $U$ must be uniform (0,1). Your example is not supported in the unit interval. Granted, the OP does not specify clearly whether the r.v. must be in (0,1) or in $\mathbb{R}$. In the later case, there are all kinds of mixture distributions that will satisfy the condition.

Comment: Thank you! I actually meant it to b supported on 0, 1.Wish i could accept both answers.

Comment: Thank you, I got it! Nice solution.